# Multi-threading in MATLAB

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I have read MATLAB's info on multi-threading and how it is in-built in certain functions.  However, my requirement is different.
Say, I have 3 functions: fun1(data1), fun2(data2), fun3(data3).... Can I implement multi-threading between these functions?  I actually have 300+ functions using a lot of data.  Multi-threading may help me cut down a lot of the time.  Please suggest a command or something which I can further research on.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to run, say, fun1 so that it uses multiple processors, or do you want to run fun1 on one processor, fun2 on a second processor, etc.?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to run a batch of different functions on different processors, you can use the Parallel Computing Toolbox, more specifically, a [parfor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brb2x2l-1.html) loop, but you need to pass the functions as a list of handles.

```
funList = {@fun1,@fun2,@fun3};
dataList = {data1,data2,data3}; %# or pass file names 

matlabpool open 

parfor i=1:length(funList)
    %# call the function
    funList{i}(dataList{i});
end
```

**Edit:**
Starting with R2015a `matlabpool` function [has been removed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/release-notes.html?searchHighlight=matlabpool) from Matlab, you need to call `parpool` instead.

Comment: And if the functions have output variables, they can be collected into a cell array, e.g. `outList{i}=funList{i}(dataList{i})`.

Comment: use matlabpool http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/distcomp/matlabpool.html command before parfor, or parfor will run with only 1 thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the [Parallel Computing Toolbox.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/distcomp_product_page.html) (I'm unfortunately not too familiar with it, but that seems to be the right place.) Look at `gather` and [parallel for-loops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bq9u0a2.html).