# Matlab's fftn gets slower with multithreading?

Tags: matlab, fftw

I have access to a 12 core machine and some matlab code that relies heavily on fftn. I would like to speed up my code.

Since the fft can be parallelized I would think that more cores would help but I'm seeing the opposite.

Here's an example:

```
X = peaks(1028);

ncores = feature('numcores');
ntrials = 20;

mtx_power_times = zeros(ncores,ntrials);
fft_times = zeros(ncores, ntrials);

for i=1:ncores
    for j=1:ntrials

        maxNumCompThreads(i);

        tic;
        X^2;
        mtx_power_times(i,j) = toc;

        tic
        fftn(X);
        fft_times(i,j) = toc;

    end
end

subplot(1,2,1);
plot(mtx_power_times,'x-')
title('mtx power time vs number of cores');

subplot(1,2,2);
plot(fft_times,'x-');
title('fftn time vs num of cores');
```

Which gives me this:
[image: Timing results for matrix multiplication and fftn]

The speedup for matrix multiplication is great but it looks like my ffts go almost 3x slower when I use all my cores. What's going on?

For reference my version is 7.12.0.635 (R2011a)

**Edit:** On large 2D arrays taking 1D transforms I get the same problem:
[image]

**Edit:** The problem appears to be that fftw is not seeing the thread limiting that maxNumCompThreads enforces. I'm getting all the cpus going full speed no matter what I set maxNumCompThreads at.

[image]

So... is there a way I can specify how many processors I want to use for an fft in Matlab?

**Edit:** Looks like I can't do this without some careful work in .mex files. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35088-how-to-control-number-of-threads-in-fft has an answer. It would be nice if someone has an easy fix...

Comment: What happens if you benchmark `fft(X,[],1)` and `fft(X,[],2)`?  (Possibly on much larger matrix sizes.)  Do those show any parallelism?  If not, the `fftw` library might not be using parallelism at all, and you may need to use a different MATLAB setting.

Comment: Consider answering your own question here, so that people can see the results of your investigation (and potentially vote it up!)...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can't do this without some careful work in .mex files. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35088-how-to-control-number-of-threads-in-fft has an answer. It would be nice if someone has an easy fix...

Answer (score -1):

To use different cores, you should use the Parallel Computing Toolbox. For instance, you could use a [parfor](http://www.mathworks.es/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html) loop, and you have to pass the functions as a list of handles:

```
function x = f(n, i)
  ...
end

m = ones(8);
parfor i=1:8
  m(i,:) = f(m(i,:), i);
end
```

More info is available at:

[High performance computing](http://www.hpc.maths.unsw.edu.au/tensor/matlab)

[Multithreaded computation](http://www.mathworks.es/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN)

[Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495000/multi-threading-in-matlab)

Comment: I'm not trying to get the for loop to run in parallel. I'm trying to make fftn go faster. The matrix multiplication automatically uses all my cores but it seems that fftn does not.

Comment: in [fftn](http://www.mathworks.es/help/techdoc/ref/fftn.html) it is said that fftn(X) is equivalent to:
Y = X;
for p = 1:length(size(X))
    Y = fft(Y,[],p);
end  

Why don´t you try to include the parfor in that 'for' loop? Hope it helps.

Comment: Those calls are made to fft in series. If I try to parallelize that with parfor then I will have a race condition on Y.

Comment: Luis, to clarify rcompton's response: fftn for multidimensional signals applies an fft in the first direction of the signal, then applies an fft to the result in the second direction of the signal, and so on.  That process is sequential and is not directly parallelizeable.